# How to iterate through divs, grab href and wrap a different element using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm really new to jQuery and only managed to do basic CSS edits so far. I don't have access to the source code, but I need to iterate through each div with class '.card', grab the href of the hyperlink and apply the link to the each respective image so the user can click on the image to in addition to the text.

I tried the following but it had unintended consequences:

- Successfully added hyperlink to each image, but was applied multiple times each
- Value of hyperlink was 'undefined'

```js
$(function() {
    $(".card-img").each(function() { // For each card
        var a = $(this).next('a'); // Find its associated anchor
        $(".card-img").wrap('<a href="' + a.attr('href') + '"></a>'); // And wrap the card image
    });
});
```

Can anyone show me how to do this?

```html
<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 1</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar1url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 2</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar2url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 3</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar3url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 4</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar4url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Apologies, I didn't realise my terrible attempt at a solution would be useful. I've updated the original post with what I tried.

Answer (score 2):

Loop over each `.card` div using `.each()` and then use `$(this)` to refer to the card div. Within the loop use `.find()` to both grab the `href` as well as `.wrap()` to wrap the image with the `href`:

```js
$('.card').each(function() {
  var href = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
  $(this).find('img').wrap(`<a href="${href}"></a>`)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-1.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 1</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar1url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 2</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar2url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-3.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 3</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar3url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



<div class="g-c g-c--md4">
  <div class="card ">
    <div class="card-img">
      <img src="webinar-4.png">
    </div>
    <div class="card-content">
      <div class="card-copy">
        <p>Webinar 4</p>
      </div>
      <a class="cta card-cta" href="https://www.webinar4url.com">Watch Webinar</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for this. When I try it, I get the following error:

"This language feature is only supported for ECMASCRIPT_2015 mode or better: template literal."

Any idea what this means?

Comment: @Mintyman Yes, that refers to `.wrap(\`<a href="${href}"></a>\`)`. To use the older way, instead use `.wrap('<a href="' + href + '"></a>')`

Comment: Aaah, got it - never even knew there was an 'old' and 'new' way. It's working with the old version now. Thank you SO much!